# Plotting dynamically and conditionally

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I have to make a plot which is getting updated after every 2 seconds (for total 20 seconds).
 In each update in range of 0 to 1 with step 0.2 i have two channels. and three options either one of them gets selected or none or both , so everytime depending on a value i want to determine among three options and want to plot in different colours.
What I can do for that ?(I have two different functions for initialization and Refresh of plots.
[image: Something like this]

Comment: If you added a code example of what you've tried, it would help.

Comment: I have added the image .. I have no clue how to do it !
I have a threshold which says whether channel is selected or not .. so its like mark the place with different markers on some conditions (not the actual value)

Comment: If you have no clue, at least you can give things a try. Do you know how to generate a single image in matplotlib? If yes, show us that code (simplified). Have you searched around for "matplotlib animation"? THe latter should yield interesting results, including some very usable examples? If you've done that, how far have you gotten in an attempt to use that in your code?

Comment: Why don't you post this as an answer to your question?

Comment: I am sorry . I am new to stackoverflow. thanks for pointing out.added as an answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution . I used like this
`def update_result(name, x, y,result):
        axes, lines = figs[name]
        if(result == 0):
           axes.plot(x,y,'g^') 
        elif(result == 1):
           axes.plot(x,y,'ro')
        elif(result == 2):
           axes.plot(x,y,'bs')`